# what is the best way to create copy of Model on save?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a simple application which has these 2 simple Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError, ObjectDoesNotExist

class Node(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.title)


class Path(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['from_node', 'to_node']

    from_node = models.ForeignKey(Node,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_node')
    to_node = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_node')
    distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} to {1}'.format(self.from_node, self.to_node)

    def clean(self):
        if self.from_node == self.to_node:
            raise ValidationError("From and to Nodes must be different ")
```

So far so good..

No what i want is to create and Manage another Mirror Copy of the Path Model like this:

Suppose we have 3 Nodes "A", "B", "C"
when a user creates a path from A & B i want to also create another mirror path from B to A which will also have the same distance.

So i added this save method to my Path model:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    super(Path, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
    try:
        mirror_path = Path.objects.get(from_node=self.to_node, to_node=self.from_node)
        if not self._state.adding:
            mirror_path.distance = self.distance
            mirror_path.save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        Path.objects.create(from_node=self.to_node, to_node=self.from_node, distance=self.distance)
```

So now when a new Path is created a mirror Path is also created,  However when any existing path is updated there is a recursion as the two models keep calling each others save method and i get Error :

> maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp

Also , I am not sure if this is the best way to do this.Should i be using a Model Manager to handle this ? Please let me know the best solution.